# Import an entire .JS (Javascript file) into another .JS file

Tags: javascript, import

How do I import an entire .js file into another.  I have seen examples where it imports certain pieces. I want to import an entire file into another .js file

```
import { msg, PI, addNumbers } from './main.js';
```

For example I have a spellCheck.js file.  spellCheck.js to have access to all the methods and variables inside of purify.min.js

Comment: Do you mean a [namespace import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#namespace_import)?

Comment: What's the use case? Are you just including files so that they can push things into the global context (eg, `window` in a browser)? (That would be my guess for your goal [based on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75560855/1028230).) If not, then you probably need to grab whatever's in the library's default export, so `import purify from './purify.min.js'` or whatever the path is.